# Passing variables owned by objects into a function

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

```
 function createPerson():void
{
 for(var i = 0;i < peopleArray.length; i++)
{
var _person = peopleArray[i];
_person.points = 10;
_person.strength = 2;
getAttribute(_person, _person.strength);// <-- Doesn't seem to want to accept _person.strength as a passable var

}
```

...

```
function getAttribute(_person, _atr):void
{
_atr = getNumber(0, 10); // Here is the problem
_person.points -= _atr;
}
```

If I replace  "_atr" with "_person.strength" (no quotes on either) the code works fine, but otherwise it doesn't change the _person.strength.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? What is getNumber()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `_atr` as `_person.strength`, `_person.strength` goes to the function as just a value.
Pass (object) `_person` and `_atr` as a string.

```
function getAttribute(_person, _atr):void
{
    _person[_atr] = getNumber(0, 10); 
    // _person[_atr] is _person.strength if _atr is "strength".
    _person.points -= _person[_atr];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. So pass the var as a string, then use [] to assign it to that object. :) I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has a second parameter, `_atr` which you pass `_person.strength` to.

However, the very first thing you do in this function is to change the value of `_atr` to some other value.
There's no point in passing anything to the `_atr` parameter, because it will be ignored anyway.

You would help yourself a lot if you specified the types of all your variables, function parameters and function return values.

Comment: You are right, but that wasn't my problem. My issue was that _atr would not be recognized at all as a var of _person. The answer below addressed this. Thanks.

Comment: @randyHurd I'd still like to know what you are trying to accomplish, relying on strings to identify properties seems to be a (very) bad idea.

Comment: "people" have points, strength, speed, agility, etc... I need to "roll" a 10 sided die (essentially) and deduct those points, and add them to each attribute. I need to do this for each "person" for each attribute.

Comment: Rather then using a line of code for each attribute after the roll... e.g. person.strength = getNumber(0,10); then person.points -= person.strength, etc...

Comment: Why would this be a very bad idea? I am pretty good with the code I know, but there is a lot I don't know. I do want to do things efficiently and correctly.

Comment: @randyHurd: accessing properties dynamically like you do with strings cannot be checked at compile time.